# On the associative property of a binary operation of the fundamental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, analytic-geometry, fundamental-groups, proof-explanation

I was reading about the proof of associativity property of the operation on the fundamental group [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812432884). The book gives the following diagram 
[image]

then it says the reader should supply the **elementary geometry** necessary to derive the homotopy
[image]

But I don't know how to do that. Please show me how to derive the above homotopy in detail so that I could try the identity and inverse properties by myself.

Answer (score 5):

I am **not** in favour of restricting to paths as maps $[0,1] \to X$. Think of a path as a journey.

Instead you can take a path of length $r \geqslant 0$ to be a map $[0,r] \to X$. Not surprisingly, a path of length $r$ composed with a path of length $s$ gives a path of length $r+s$, and this composition is associative. You also have paths of length $0$, of course. Thus the paths on $X$ now form a category, say $P(X)$.

The question of the appropriate equivalence relation on $P(X)$  to give the fundamental group(oid) has to be discussed, and also reparametrisation to get a path of length $1$ from a path of length $r$. An account of this approach is in the book T&G= [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html). The classic book by Crowell and Fox on "Knot theory"  also uses paths of length $r$, with a different but equivalent approach.

When I was writing the first edition of T&G in the 1960s I found several examples in the literature of complicated formulae with accompanying diagram, and I worked hard to get an account which avoided them as much as possible, and which I could understand. On one occasion this led to an entirely new result, a gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences.  Groupoids came in when I tried to get a new proof that the fundamental group of the circle is the integers. See the discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one.

Just to add a point: if one takes an aesthetic view of mathematics, and that one is looking for proofs which make things clear, then one look at the formula given for $H(t,s)$ should make one feel that there must be a better way.

In 1958 I overheard a comment of Raoul Bott on Alexander Grothendieck, part of which was that "Grothendieck was prepared to work very hard to make arguments almost tautological".