# Loops: associativity for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How would you show that for any three loops $x, y, z$ that $(x*y)*z$ is equivalent to $x*(y*z)$. 
I want to show that $([x]*[y])*[z] = [x]*([y]*[z])$.

I am terrible at this stuff, would appreciate a good explanation and step by step proof or what I would need to do for proof. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more context. How do you mean 'loop' here and what is $*$ and $[-]$?

Comment: It's just a question of writing a suitable homotopy between the paths.

Comment: See [my notes here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/09.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a homeomorphism $p:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $x*(y*z)=((x*y)*z)\circ p,$ and then use that any two paths $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ are homotopic.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant to this is my answer to [On the associative property of a binary operation of the fundamental group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237690/on-the-associative-property-of-a-binary-operation-of-the-fundamental-group/1238059#1238059) which shows you can define a path of length $r \geqslant 0$ from $x$ to $y$ to be a map $f: [0,r] \to X$ such that $f(0)=x, f(r) = y$. Composition of paths is then **associative**.  If  further $s \geqslant 0$ define  $f +s$ to be $f$ on $[0,r]$ and constant on $[r,r+s]$. Define  $f$ of length $r$ and $f'$ of length $r'$ to be *equivalent* if there are $s,s'$ such that $f+s, f'+s'$ are of the same length and are homotopic rel end points. You easily show any path is equivalent to a path  of length $1$. In this way you get some easier proofs for  the main properties  of the fundamental group and groupoid.